# Why does xsl:sort work when I omit a select attribute but not when I define it?

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

Given this XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <section xml:id="known_issues">
        <title>Known Issues</title>
        <informaltable>
            <tgroup>
                <thead>
                    <row>
                        <entry>
                            ...
                        </entry>
                        <entry>
                            ...
                        </entry>
                        <entry>
                            ...
                        </entry>
                        <entry>
                            ...
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//item">
                        <xsl:sort/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </tbody>
            </tgroup>
        </informaltable>
    </section>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <row>
        <entry>
            <xsl:value-of select="key"/>  
        </entry>
        <entry>
            ...
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <xsl:value-of select="component"/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            ...
        </entry>
    </row>
</xsl:template>
```

For this XML:

```
<rss>
   <channel>
      <item>
         ...
         <key id="105988">BUG-345345</key>
         ...
         <summary>Improved stuff for the thing</summary>
         ...
         <component>foo</component>
         ...
      </item>
      <item>
         ...
      </item>
      <item>
         ...
      </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

It processes the XML I'm transforming in the way I expect. The processed data is generated as a four column table.

What I want to focus on is the `xsl:sort` instruction. If I don't apply a `@select` attribute, the data is successfully sorted by the first column.

However, I want to sort based on the third column (named "component" in the source data). If I apply a `select="component"` attribute to `xsl:sort`, the transform fails with the error: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the @select attribute of xsl:sort. Why is this the case? The `component` element is a sibling to the `key` element. Isn't the `key` element also a "sequence of more than one item"? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example - including the input. Minimizing the code to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem would be also welcome - see: [mcve]

Comment: It is likely that you have `item` elements with multiple `component` elements. Either add a predicate to select the first(or last) `component`, use `string-join()` to concatenate them, or do something that would give you a single value to use as the sort key. Post an example XML that exhibits the behavior and we can more easily diagnose and help....

Comment: @MadsHansen Thanks for the tip. Adding a predicate solved my problems. Sorry for not providing sample input as it is just a hideously huge dump of data into XML. I've provided a small sample for what it's worth.

Comment: @JasonDavis Except your sample does not exhibit the problem.

Comment: You also need to tell us whether you are using an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 processor, and whether the stylesheet specifies version="1.0" or "2.0". In 1.0, or in 2.0 running in backwards compatibility mode, xsl:sort works on the first item selected and ignores other items. In 2.0 it's an error if there are multiple items. The message suggests 2.0.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thank you for pointing that out. I wasn't aware of that. The stylesheet is 2.0 and I'm using Saxon-PE 9.6.0.7. The problem was that some of the processed `item` elements contained multiple occurrences of `component` elements.

Comment: @MadsHansen If you want to convert your comment into an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @JasonDavis - That's okay. You should post an example of what you implemented with an explanation as the answer and accept it. I'd gladly give you an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the pool of data that I was working with in most cases just had a single `component` for each `item`. My thinking was that if there was more than one component that applied, there would still be a single field for defining it and the values would be delimited somehow. However, that was not the case. I ended up with something like this.

```
<rss>
  <channel>
     <item>
        ...
        <key id="105988">BUG-345345</key>
        ...
        <summary>Improved stuff for the thing</summary>
        ...
        <component>foo</component>
        ...
     </item>
     <item>
        ...
        <key id="105932">BUG-355344</key>
        ...
        <summary>Fixed some stuff for the thing</summary>
        ...
        <component>bar</component>
        ...
     </item>
     <item>
        ...
        <key id="106978">BUG-244345</key>
        ...
        <summary>Nothing to see here...</summary>
        ...
        <component>foo</component>
        <component>foo2</component>
        ...
     </item>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

I ended up using a predicate to only process the first occurrence of a `component`:

```
...
<tbody>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="//item">
      <xsl:sort select="component[1]"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
</tbody>
...
```

So, although using a predicate "solved" my problem, I'm not convinced it's the best solution as ignoring a possibly relevant piece of information may dilute the resultant transform. At least, I figured out what the problem was and why my sorts were failing. Turns out the error message was very specifically correct.

Here is what I did to fix it once and for all:

```
<tbody>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="//item">
      <xsl:sort select="string-join(component, ' ')"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
</tbody>
```

I just joined the values together delimited by a space (if multiple `components` exist).

Comment: "*I'm not convinced it's the best solution as ignoring a possibly relevant piece of information may dilute the resultant transform.*" You need to provide a better explanation of what you want to happen when there are multiple `component` elements under the same `item`. At least that's what I think you mean by "*ignoring a possibly relevant piece of information*". If the other  `component` elements are relevant to the sorting process, you need to tell us **exactly** how to use each one of them.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Done. Thanks for the prodding. ;)